# Rails Encrypted Columns that Still Allow for Searching

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, search, encryption

I have a rails application that requires that I encrypt some columns in the database.

I already have, based on many examples, the user password and email encrypted.  That seemed easy even for a noob like me.

The specific challenge is that I'm developing an application for attorneys (really one atty), and I want to encrypt their client's names and addresses so that if the database is stolen, that data is not readable.  The problem is that the end user (the attorney) will want to search by client.

I'm assuming that based on my requirements, despite the debate (though probably a lack of knowledge), that encryption in the database is the right way to go. I think otherwise the searching will be very difficult in the application. It seems possible to setup the database so that keys can be passed into the database from somewhere else when it starts up, so that the keys aren't in a file on the server somewhere.

Actually, I'm mot even sure that the kind of encryption I'm looking for is possible or practical. I've read a bit and searched, but thus far, I've found no clear solutions. Below are the most promising things I've looked at. All seem powerful and creative solutions. Please help me correct any mis-impressions and point out, if such exists, solutions that might work. As always, thanks.

**attr_encrypted**

Application encryption, but I don't think practical search is possible.

**pgcrypto**

Makes use of postgresql's database encryption, but it's not Rails 4.0, and I can't seem to make it so. Not certain it would do what I want anyway.

**jmazzi/crypt_keeper**

Makes use of postgresql's database encryption, but doesn't allow for the the kind of searching of the client data that would work.

Comment: Any solution to this? I am facing same problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a technique called [blind indexing](https://paragonie.com/blog/2017/05/building-searchable-encrypted-databases-with-php-and-sql) you can use for this. An advantage of this approach is the database never sees the secret key.

Here's a [Ruby implementation](https://github.com/ankane/blind_index) I created. You can create indexes on expressions for fuzzier searches.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  blind_index :initials, attribute: :name, expression: ->(v) { v.split(" ").map(&:first) }, ...
  blind_index :phone_last4, attribute: :phone, expression: ->(v) { v.last(4) } ...
end
```

Be very selective with how you use this, as it leaks the fact certain rows contain the same indexed data.

This is not 100% the same as doing `LIKE` queries. An efficient way to index for `LIKE` queries is [trigrams](http://blog.scoutapp.com/articles/2016/07/12/how-to-make-text-searches-in-postgresql-faster-with-trigram-similarity). However, if you create trigrams and blind index them, an attacker could use frequency analysis to decipher the data.

Comment: Thanks for this Andrew.  I appreciate all the effort that you and offers have put into providing info on this topic. Even more would be great!  Like your reference to frequency analysis puzzles me. If each item is salted, what would frequency analysis show? I guess the trigram must somehow 'unmask' the data? Which makes sense, how else would the query work without checking every item in the column?

Comment: If you use blind indexing on trigrams, frequency analysis will show the frequency of trigrams, which can allow an attacker to figure out the data. Here's how frequency analysis works: https://learncryptography.com/attack-vectors/frequency-analysis

Comment: Thanks, but the frequency part was the only part I understood. I still don't get it though. If a salt is added to each password '123456' then it and another '123456' aren't the same. And if no two elements that are the same, how is the frequency analysis performed?

Answer (score 3):

According to **[attr-encrypted/README.rdoc](https://github.com/attr-encrypted/attr_encrypted/blob/master/README.rdoc)** search is possible. There is a warning that it will only work if all records are encrypted with the same key per attribute.

The example given is:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_encrypted :email, :key => 'a secret key'
  attr_encrypted :password, :key => 'some other secret key'
end

# You can now lookup and login users like so:
User.find_by_email_and_password('test@example.com', 'testing')
```

Comment: Thanks Frank. I'm looking at it again, but it seems not to allow searches except in the sense that the hashes match.  (I think.) Sorting and "like" searches seem problematic, but maybe it's just a misunderstanding on my part.

Comment: Ah, yes I hadn't considered fuzzy searches or sorting. It seems like the only way to get sorting to work would be to do it in ruby after retrieving all the records. Most unfortunate.

Comment: So the link below to a question and answer has a workable search solution.  Basically what is does is decrypt each column value one by one and compare. It's not too bad, but again, I think it's probably better done in the database.  I suppose the sort issue could be addressed with a new column that is in the same order as the columns that are encrypted, but that is a poor work around.

Answer (score 1):

The [encrypt_column](https://github.com/danlherman/encrypt_column) gem has a searchable option that uses a hash for searching and adds a with_ method to the class.

Comment: I'll look at it Dan, and I'm way above my weight-class with this stuff, but I no longer think a solution is really possible, even theoretically. To be really secure, as I think we now know, a column must be salted and then encrypted. You have to have a separate salt for each value. Given those constraints, I don't understand how you could have a "fuzzy" search (a LIKE in SQL) let alone a straight match search.

Comment: It doesn't use a fuzzy search. What it does is store a hash field in the db for the encrypted plaintext based on a specified salt (along with the encrypted ciphertext in a separate db column). The search method then takes the plaintext, hashes it using the salt, and searches for the value using that hashed value.

Comment: Thanks Dan.  So, a "like" SQL query can't work.  (Which is what I meant by "fuzzy".)

Answer (score 0):

What the problem with searching for `crypt_keeper` gem?

https://github.com/jmazzi/crypt_keeper#searching

```
Model.search_by_plaintext(:field, 'searchstring')
# With a scope
Model.where(something: 'blah').search_by_plaintext(:field, 'searchstring')
```

Comment: Andrey - The "Searching" section of the gem README.md covers the issue.  That said, I think I should do some research on what I've said and various use cases and how this all works, so I can explain the issue better.